# Retrieve all data from SQL array LIKE a given value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop, sql-like

I'm trying to retrieve all the data id from a database where their tags(array) is like a given value.
This is what I have done so far...

```
$new_string = 'nice phone';
$construct = mysql_query("SELECT tag_array, name, id FROM details 
WHERE tag_array LIKE $new_string%")
or die("<p>died 20: $construct<br>" . mysql_error());

while($getThis = mysql_fetch_array($construct)){
echo $getThis['id'].'<br />';
echo stripslashes($getThis['name']).'<br />';
}
```

It doesn't work ATALL.
Could you please point me to the right direction?
I'm really struggling!!

Comment: "It doesn't work AT ALL."  So what *does* happen?

Comment: i added the single quotes, sorry that was typo. It doesn't match the words with all word in the array. on the first word. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put $new_string in quotes.

**NOTE** It is very bad practice and you should always escape all variables you are passing to SQL. You should really read up on SQL injection and other security issues.

Also if you want to match $new_string anywhere in tag_array (which you most likely want), you need to add dollar sign in front of it too. You can read up more at [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html).

So in the end:

```
"SELECT tag_array, name, id FROM details WHERE tag_array LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($new_string) . "%'"
```

Comment: @Konerak: Thanks. I am aware of that, but simply forgot to escape.

Comment: i added the single quotes, sorry that was typo. It doesn't match the words with all word in the array. on the first word. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Just to be clear. Array1 is = (boys, girls, tables, chairs). word to search is tables. it doesnt echo Array1 because it only compares with first word.

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly, but you need to add % in front of and at the end of searched word, if you want to find this word anywhere in tag_array. As now it only searches tag_arrays that start with your word.

Answer (score 0):

You should sanitise the data before putting it in the query like:

```
  $new_string = "blah...; DROP TABLE tag_array; #";
  $sql = mysql_real_escape_string($new_string);
  $sql = "SELECT tag_array, name, id FROM details WHERE tag_array LIKE %'$sql'%"
```

This is not enough though it just helps preventing sql inject, consider using regular expressions to clean the data. If you don't yet know about regexp check out this site: [regexp info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). It helped me mutch.

Comment: Please add a comment about your problem (downvoting).